# move all root domain url to subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

hi everyone i am new to stackoverflow and not php developer

i am trying to move my wordpress site to subdirectory

example: http: //blog.site.com -> http: //blog.site.com/blog

i did some google and found some code for htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blog.site.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
```

this redirecting my home page to http: //blog.site.com/blog.
but not
http: //blog.site.com/index.php/category/pageName/

now after more doing more google i got one more code for htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blog.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blog.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog/index.php [L]
```

using this code
http: //blog.site.com/index.php/category/pageName/
is reading response from
http: //blog.site.com/blog/index.php/category/pageName/
but not redirecting

I want to redirect all url
example 
http: //blog.site.com/........ --> http: //blog.site.com/blog/......

Help me... Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blog.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R,L]
```

The R added is Redirect..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ferry Kobus for reply

I also got one solution its is almost same and work perfectly.

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blog.site.com$
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,R=301]

anyways thanks again.